# Odd MySQL error on custom WordPress query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to run a MySQL query via WordPress, to bring back a list of posts that I want to delete because they have no "like" votes (using someone else's plugin data). The query works perfectly in phpMyAdmin but gives a syntax error when I run it through WP... and I see absolutely no reason why it would do this.

Here's the query code, which checks for posts over 30 days old that have no corresponding "like" entry in wti_like_post (whether positive or negative):

```
$novotesquery = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
                 WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
                 AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
                 AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                 AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN 
                 (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->wti_like_post)" ;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($novotesquery);
```

The syntax error says there's a problem on the last line of the SQL (the SELECT in parentheses): "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 6".

When I run the query in phpMyAdmin (replacing "$wpdb->" with the table prefix), it works a treat. If anyone can tell me why the SQL query will run on the server and not in WP, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wp_wti_like_post on a standard install - it depends on the DB prefix defined in the config.

Comment: Thanks to the comment and answer, I found out what was wrong. As usual, assumption is the mother of all screwups!

I assumed "$wpdb->wti_like_post" converted to "DBprefix_wti_like_post", as "$wpdb->posts" converts to "DBprefix_posts". My assumption was wrong. It doesn't convert to anything at all, as far as I can see, presumably because it's not a built-in WordPress table.

What's needed is "**{$wpdb->prefix}wti_like_post**", which forces the DB prefix into place.

It works now.

Thanks very much to both commenters for the mental prompt from asking how the value comes out!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's just a matter of defensive parenthesis

```
$novotesquery = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts}
                 WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post'
                 AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'
                 AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                 AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID NOT IN 
                 (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->wti_like_post})" ;
```

Perhaps you should use $wpdb->query method instead of get_results and finally, perhaps wti_like_posts is not yet declared when your code runs.

What about die($novotesquery) right before "$result" line?